# Hiding Kotlin Operator overloading function in java

Tags: java, kotlin, operator-overloading

I have a library that I'm developing for kotlin users, and I'm also kinda supporting Java.

One of my functions is 'add'
It looks similar to this

```
open fun add(element: T, position: Int = elements.size) {
    elements.add(position, element)

    if (!updateUi) return
    if (isUiThread()) notifyItemInserted(position) else throw uiThreadException
}
```

Which is great, to make it a bit cooler I added an Operator overloading function for the spoken 'add' function which looks like this

```
open operator fun plus(element: T): Unit = add(element)
```

The problem is when a java user uses it looks like a duplicate function which can cause some confusion

Kotlin:

```
someClass.add(item)
someClass + item
```

Java:

```
someClass.add(item);
someClass.plus(item);
```

In the Java version, it's not that clear which one you should use and I want to hide it for java users.

I tried changing the name using `@JvmName` but I can't use it if the function is 'open function' which I want it to be because I want to give the user the possibility to change it if that's the desire.

Do I have a way to hide it? if not any other solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Would it be that bad to have both especially when `add()` gets called in the end? You could add some documentation though. Java users are used to this after all, there are several cases where multiple methods actually do the same thing.

Comment: That's what I'll do if I won't receive any solution, but that also forces me to make the function 'closed'

Comment: have you tried `internal` on plus function.?

Comment: @Moinkhan But that will also remove the functionality from kotlin users...

Comment: Unless you want `plus` to be changed _independently from `add`_, there's no need for it to be `open` and you can use `@JvmName`.

Comment: @ Alexey Romanov I don't mind if it's the same or not I just don't want to force it on my users

Comment: As Alexy Romanov has said, just don't make the operator method open. There should be no reason that `add` and `plus` should diverge in implementation.